# laravel auto create random string

Tags: php, laravel-5, php-7

how do i automatically generate string i want the string to increment every time i hit submit button for example i have string TEST0001,next should be TEST0002,TEST0003,TEST0004,untill the end.

**Migration Table**

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('leads', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('generate_id');
        $table->string('name')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Controller:**

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
    $this->validate($request, [


           'generate_id'=>'required|Unique',


            ]);
            $leads=new lead();
            $leads->generate_id=$request->generate_id;
            $leads->name=$request->name;
            $leads->save();

            return redirect()->route('leads.index')
        ->with('flash_message', 'Success.');
}
```

Comment: If you're using an auto incrementing ID on the table, why not just append that to the word TEST when you create the record?

Comment: how to append? auto increment id is the primary key idnt want to touch it. and somemore  its integer it wont allow string thats why i want to create secondary which is string so i make it as sub id..

Comment: I mean just use the auto increment value to create the `genterate_id` value not actually edit the auto increment value.